# Sentence boundary detection across many languages

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm looking for a framework like below that can be used with swift.
What do you recommend?

https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in apple [NSLinguisticTagger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger) provided that it covers the languages you need.  One of the tags it can recognize is a sentence.